# How to get current or focused cell value?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

When I select a cell, the respective column it gets focused. For I need to get the Column value and Row value (row #) on excel worksheet wherever focus changes.

How can I do the same through code?

How do I get the focused or current cell's column value in VSTO excel using C#?

Comment: You should accept answers to previous questions before asking new questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) this.Application.ActiveCell;

//get the cell value
object cellValue = rng.Value;

//get the row and column details
int row = rng.Row;
int column = rng.Column;
```

[and here's a quick start walkthrough](http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-office-excel-programming-using-vsto).