# How to write to Excel cell next to selected cell?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

My program reads data (Names) from an Excel Document and displays them on a CheckListBox for the user to then select their name. The user then must select a color from a range of RadioButtons. How do I get the program to write the color that they selected in the cell next to the cell that contains their name?

Below is an extract from my program:

```
public void ColorChoice()
    {
        ColorGreen.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        ColorYellow.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        ColorRed.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        ColorBlue.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
    }

    void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton Color = sender as RadioButton;

        if (Color == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Color Selected");
            return;
        }

        // Ensure that the RadioButton.Checked property
        // changed to true.
        if (Color.Checked)
        {
            // Keep track of the selected RadioButton by saving a reference
            // to it
            string SelectedColor = Color.Text;

            //This is where it will write the color to the Excel File
            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\Users\\Blayne\\Desktop\\Prototype3\\Prototype1\\Prototype1\\Save Folder\\Students.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 1, 0);
            Excel._Worksheet ExcelSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)ExcelBook.Sheets[1];


        }


    }

    public void ImportStudentDetails()
    {
        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\Users\\Blayne\\Desktop\\Prototype3\\Prototype1\\Prototype1\\Save Folder\\Students.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 1, 0);
        Excel._Worksheet ExcelSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)ExcelBook.Sheets[1];

        NameListBox.CheckOnClick = true;
        NameListBox.Name = "NameListBox";
        NameListBox.TabIndex = 1;
        NameListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        NameListBox.ThreeDCheckBoxes = true;
        NameListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[2, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[3, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[4, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[5, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[6, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[7, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[8, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[9, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[10, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[11, 1].text);
        Controls.Add(NameListBox);

    }



    public class SaveName
    {
        public static void SaveNameData(object obj, string filename)

        {

            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        private string name1;

        public string Name1
        {
            get { return name1; }
            set { name1 = value; }
        }
    }



    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var SNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var c in NameListBox.CheckedItems)
        {
            SNames.Add(c.ToString());
        }

        string SName = string.Join(",", SNames.ToArray());
        try
        {
            Data info = new Data();
            info.Name1 = SName;
            Login.SaveName.SaveNameData(info, "Name.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        this.Hide();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        f2.Show();

    }

    public static void SaveStudentData(object data, string directory)
    {
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(directory, true))
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
            sr.Serialize(writer, data);
            writer.Close();
        }

    }
```

Ignore that my program writes the name selected to a xml file as that is so it can transfer the name to another form.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you get the current cell:

[How to get current or focussed cell value in Excel worksheet using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378206/how-to-get-current-or-focussed-cell-value-in-excel-worksheet-using-c-sharp)

Just add 1 to rng.Column and it will give you the cell next to the current cell.

Then you can assign the colour you want to either text or background:

Comment: I edited the program using the code that you suggested and implemented it. However, the program doesn't seem to be picking up the active cell as it is just writing to the second column of the first row.

Comment: Sounds like the rgn.row property wasn't assigned a value?

Comment: Perhaps, I believe that it may be the fact the ExcelApp.ActiveCell; is not picking up the cell of which the user has selected their name from the CheckListBox.

Comment: If you debug, can you then see that rgn.row and rgn.column are assigned?

Comment: I ran the debug and I can confirm that both of them are receiving values. To be more specific, rgn.row is always receiving 1 and rgn.column is always receiving 2 (which is good).

Comment: Seems like your rgn variable is another object?

Comment: I shouldn't think so. Here is the code I wrote under the section labelled "This is where it will write the color to the Excel File" above:

   Excel.Range rgn = (Excel.Range)ExcelApp.ActiveCell;
   
    object cellValue = rgn.Value;

    int row = rgn.Row;
    int column = rgn.Column + 1;

    ExcelSheet.Cells[row, column] = SelectedColor;

    ExcelBook.Save();
    ExcelBook.Close();
    ExcelApp.Quit();